# rxjs - is there an always operator? how do you always do something?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs6

I've got an NGRX effect (heavily uses RxJS) as follows:

```
@Effect()
allFiltersRequested$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<AllFiltersRequestedAction>(FiltersActionTypes.AllFiltersRequested),
  tap((action) => debug(action)),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectAllFilters))),
  filter(([action, allFilters]) => isEmpty(allFilters)),
  mergeMap(() =>
    this.simService.getAllFilters().pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of({})
      })
    )
  ),
  map((allFilters) => new AllFiltersLoadedAction(allFilters))
)
```

I am using `filter` to prevent an HTTP request being made (see `mergeMap`) if the store is already populated (since the data from the API does not change)

However, I always want to execute:

```
map((allFilters) => new AllFiltersLoadedAction(allFilters))
```

regardless as to whether the HTTP request was made or not. It can't however be executed before `mergeMap` because `mergeMap` ensures that the `allFilters` data is available.

Are there any RxJS `always do this` type operators? If not, how should I refactor this code to achieve what I want?

At the moment, the only solution is to remove `filter` but that will result in needless HTTP requests being made.

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you add an examples of the data arriving and transformed by each part of the pipe.

Comment: Maybe observable.amb would help here? New to RxJS, so I'm just guessing and hoping it will help. http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Amb

Comment: Have you tried the finalize operator?

Comment: finalize not quite what I want ... finalize = Call a function when observable completes or errors ... what i want = Call a function when observable emits after all other piped functions are executed ... but thx

Comment: What is data type of `allFilters` ?

Comment: its a JSON object

Comment: Hmm....which `isEmpty` method implementation are you using?  Is it from external library like `lodash`?  I got it confused for sometime with `isEmtpy` of RxJs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't use `filter` and wrap the HTTP call with an `if` condition:

```
...
withLatestFrom(...)
mergeMap(([action, allFilters]) => {
  if (isEmpty(allFilters)) {
    return of(allFilters);
  }
  return this.simService.getAllFilters()...
})
map((allFilters) => new AllFiltersLoadedAction(allFilters))
```

I don't know what exactly you want to do but I hope you'll get the point.

Comment: this looks useful, ill have a play +1 - will accept if i get nothing better soon

Comment: Shouldn't service be called when `if (isEmpty(allFilters))` is `true`?